# display a new image as user scrubs audio javascript

Tags: javascript, math, audio

Scenario, as a user scrubs an audio file I want to display a new image in the background of audio player div. Audio files have different images, some have 8 images some have 42 and so on. Audio files have different lengths.

we have our length: 30000 ms.
we have our image count for audio file: 13.
we have our url: http://www.foostorage.com/api/image_1.jpg

```
const duration = 30000
const imageCount = 13
const url = 'http://www.foostorage.com/api/image_1.png'

function renderImage(percentage) {
  const ab = Math.round((percentage / imageCount) * 100);
  const fooImage = url.replace(/poster.*.png/, `poster_${ab}.jpg`);
  return fooImage;
}
```

The percentage is coming from the scrub position, ex: `0.232` would be 23% out of 100.

Hopefully i explained this ok, feel free to let me know if I haven't

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
const duration = 30000
const imageCount = 13
const url = 'http://www.foostorage.com/api/image_1.png'

function renderImage(percentage) {
  const ab = Math.round((percentage * imageCount));
  const fooImage = url.replace(/image.*.png/, `poster_${ab}.jpg`);
  return fooImage;
}

// Assuming scrub scale 0-1
console.log(renderImage(0.1325));
console.log(renderImage(0.20));
console.log(renderImage(0.336));
console.log(renderImage(0.85));
console.log(renderImage(1));
```

Comment: This is is, thank you for showing me that I need to improve my math skills :)